# gcc and liboauth - linker can't find oauth.h

Tags: c, gcc, oauth, linker

I'm trying to use liboauth with a C program, using gcc as my compiler, and no matter what I've tried I keep getting the error "ld: library not found for -loauth" and "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1".

I'm including the header via "#include <oauth.h>", and my most-recent call to gcc looked like this:

```
gcc -Wall -lcurl -loauth -I /usr/local/include -v -o api api.c
```

Now, oauth.h does exist in /usr/local/include, and there are a handful of liboauth files (including liboauth.a) located in /usr/local/bin, which I'm assuming were placed there when I ran the install.  I will admit that I'm not very familiar with gcc and compiling non-trivial C programs, but I was able to get libcurl working on a fresh download in just a few minutes.  I just can't figure out what's going on with liboauth.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *are sure* liboauth's located in /usr/local/bin use

```
gcc -Wall -L/usr/local/bin -I /usr/local/include -v -o api api.c -lcurl -loauth
```

It'd also be better to place libraries in the end of the command as there is some important stuff with them (they may depend on each other, etc).

By the way, it's pretty strange your libraries are in /usr/local/bin as *libraries* are almost always stored in some path like /usr/*/lib.

Comment: You're right, I meant /usr/local/lib, not /usr/local/bin, and your suggestion worked!  Do you have any idea why I need to specify -L/usr/local/lib for oauth, but not for curl?

Comment: That could mean libcurl was installed _not_ in /usr/local/lib. It could be in /usr/lib, for example.